# Higland.js: wrap toCallback into promise

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bluebird, highland.js

I want to write something like:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const H = require('highland')

Promise.fromCallback(
  H([1, 2, 3]).toCallback
).then(function(val) {
  expect(val).eql(1, 2, 3)
})
```

But I see an error:

```
TypeError: this.consume is not a function
```

How do I properly bind the context in the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that .toCallback loses it's contests, so `this` is not a stream anymore and that's why `this.consume` is not a function.

The easies way to solve is to wrap it with an arrow function.

```
cb => H([1, 2, 3]).toCallback(cb)
```

The second thing is that you cannot use toCallback with the steams emitting multiple values, because it'll throw an error. (Please check [the docs](http://highlandjs.org/#toCallback))

To fix it you could call `.collect()` like this:

```js
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const H = require('highland');
const assert = require('assert');

Promise.fromCallback(
 cb => H([1, 2, 3]).collect().toCallback(cb)
).then(function(val) {
 assert.deepEqual(val, [1, 2, 3]);
 console.log('All good.');
});
```